# switch to classic view for invited users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, external-users, popup

We need the *classic view* because it shows a cookie based **popup**, this already works with a script-editor webpart, unfortunately modern view doesn't allow scripting. Asking for *any other solution?*

Our problem is that **invited users can't switch to classic view**.
I had setted classic user experience in advanced options but other users still view only the modern.
with my admin account i can easly switch between the views.

Finally, we want to set **the deafult-permission** level for **invited users** to a custom permission, that costum permission doesn't allow to delete items, how we can perform that?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online modern page, you need to use [SPFx web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) which provides full support for client-side SharePoint development, easy integration with SharePoint data, and extending Microsoft Teams.

Per my test, when you set the default list experience to classic, make sure you are also using classic view, then the invited user will access the list view as classic.

[image]

You could create a new permission level without delete items permission as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer,
I' ve developed a simple popup web-part with SPFx and works well for modern pages but doesn't works with document libraries as we want to do (because it cant't be added inside libraries but only in pages).
Then I tried to set the default list experience to classic, using classic view, but invited user still access the view as modern.

Comment: Please remove the SPFx web part in the page and return to the classic expernience to test again, per  my test it works well and I don't use SPFx web part.

Comment: Ok, we solved with a custom SPFx content extension who inject the popup directly in the modern view. thanks